# Mocking / facade for SQL Server with a service?

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-2008, service

Is it possible to mock, or create a facade, to replace a SQL Server database in-place, currently being used directly by a website via ADO.net, with a service (ideally WCF or other .NET technology)?

**Example**:
Consider an ASP.NET website with a lot of features which use SQL Server 2008 over ADO.NET.  The SQL transactions involve many stored stored procedures, though there are some direct T-SQL transactions.  It would be powerful to be able to replace the (singular) SQL server with a more scalable implementation, *without* having to re-implement the website features.

This could be a shim for ADO.NET, or an ODBC driver to a custom service framework, or something else.  The "right" answer may seem to be "reimplement the website to use a more abstracted data interface", but let's consider that the website code is immutable (though configuration could be altered).

Comment: "We've gotten to the point where scaling our database and adding new features have become prohibitively expensive" - why? need indexes?

Comment: How is this service supposed to help matters? Are you having a performance problem, or is it just a complexity problem?

Comment: If things are getting too complex I really don't think adding this really unusual implementation is going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply provide an data access layer that specifies well designed interfaces. Your website will only ever have a handle on an interface, and you can use dependency injection/IoC to provide your concrete implementation of your interface on an as needs basis.

It's not an "existing technology" as such, but probably just a prudent way forward in your design I'd suggest.

Comment: While that answer is obviously the ideal goal, and while I'm not a .NET expert, it does seemt to me that by writing a custom ADO.NET driver, one could accomplish what was specifically asked.